# PHP foreach loop problem

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have the following code:

```
//generate 10 top tags
$tagSQL = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags"));
$topArray = array();
foreach($tagSQL as $poland)
{
    if($poland["tagID"] == 1)
    {
        $topArray[0] ++;
    }
    if($poland["tagID"] == 2)
    {
        $topArray[1] ++;
    }
    if($poland["tagID"] == 3)
    {
        $topArray[2] ++;
    }
    if($poland["tagID"] == 4)
    {
        $topArray[3] ++;
    }
}
function printTopTags()
{
    $n = 0;
    foreach($topArray as $buddha)
    {
        $n = $n + 1;
        if(sizeOf($topArray) > $n)
        {
            $hersheyBar = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            $hersheyBar = "";
        }
        $finalFinalEndArray = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT tagName FROM tags WHERE tagID = '$buddha'"));
        foreach($finalFinalEndArray as $waterBottle)
        {
            echo $waterBottle . $hersheyBar;
        }
    }   
}
```

I get the error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 93`

Line 93 is `foreach($topArray as $buddha)`.

Any help?

Comment: `var_dump($topArray);` ps: you ask trivial questions for several weeks in a row. Isn't it simpler to read some php book for newbies?

Answer (score 1):

http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Also

```
if($poland["tagID"] == 1)
{
    $topArray[0] ++;
}
if($poland["tagID"] == 2)
{
    $topArray[1] ++;
}
if($poland["tagID"] == 3)
{
    $topArray[2] ++;
}
if($poland["tagID"] == 4)
{
    $topArray[3] ++;
}
```

===

```
if ($poland["tagID"] >= 1 && $poland["tagID"] <= 4)
    $topArray[$poland["tagID"] - 1]++;
```

Comment: RTFM has no place in a stackoverflow answer -1

Comment: @Toby Allen: I know, and I agree with -1, but he asks the 100% manual questions already for several weeks. SO is for specialists, not for people who just give tasks for community and copy-paste results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tagSQL = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags"));
```

This is very bad practice. If the query fails for any reason whatsoever, mysql_query returns boolean FALSE, which you then blindly pass to mysql_fetch_array, which will then fail in turn because it's expect a mysql result handle, not a boolean, and return a boolean itself.

You then use all this failed data in a foreach loop, and wonder why you're not getting anything but errors?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed all of this to be more SQL based than PHP based.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $topArray just not defined in printTopTags() function.
You can pass it as a parameter:

```
function printTopTags($topArray) {
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

$topArray is a global variable.

To use it inside a function you either have to pass it as a parameter or use the global keyword to import it:

```
function printTopTags()
{
    global $topArray;  // <---- Here!
    $n = 0;
    foreach($topArray as $buddha)
```

Comment: Just what caused this -1 after 3 years ;)